# In a RESTFul API, what's the correct http verb to a revert / rollback action?

Tags: rest

Imagine a simple document management webservice strutured like this:

```
document/  
    GET -> retrieves all documents
    POST -> creates a new document

document/[id]
    GET -> retrieves the "latest" revision of document specified by ID
    POST -> creates a new revision of the document

document/[id]/revision
    GET -> retrieves all revisions of the document
    POST -> Alias to POST->document/[id]

document/[id]/revision/[revisionID]
    GET -> retrieves the specified revision of the document
```

Now, let's say I want to rollback a document to a previous arbitrary revision (for instance, from revision 5 to 3).

In a RESTful point of view, what **ROUTE** and what **VERB** should be used for this kind of operation? Should I create a new verb for rollback operations?

Keep in mind that in a rollback operation nothing is deleted. Internally, the server just recognises a different revision number as the latest.

Comment: In a RESTful point of view, the route doesn't matter, and the method depends on whether the operation is idempotent or not. Trying to rollback to the same revision as the current should do nothing or return an error?

Comment: @PedroWerneck Should do nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have the representations for each revision available, and the rollback operation should be idempotent, the most straightforward approach would be simply doing a `PUT` to `document/[id]` with the contents of `GET document/[id]/revision/[revisionid]`, for the `revisionid` you want `document/[id]` to be set to.